# How to find the third entry of a while loop

Tags: python

For the array `x= np.random.uniform(low=0,high=50, size = 10000)`, use a while loop to determine the number of random entries required to find the third entry that exceeds 36.

I know how to find a number that exceeds 36 but I'm not sure how to find the third number that exceeds it.

```
i=0 
x= np.random.uniform(low=0,high=50, size = 10000)
while x[i] >= 36:
  i+=1 
print(i)
```

Comment: You need to keep track of a count of the numbers you find over 36 and break out of the loop when that count reaches three. And your loop condition should be `while i < len(x)`. Note, one would never use a while loop here

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment? You seem to be focusing this wrong. Try looping over the elements in `x`, rather than using the current while loop

Comment: @yatu if it is a homework problem it looks like it's specifically asking to use a while loop in the instructions

Comment: Yes, but I said rather than using the current while loop, instead of perhaps loopping over a range, which can also be done with a while loop of course @NickDima

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the matched numbers into a list, and make the while loop break while the length of list equals 3. The last value of the list is your answer.

```
import numpy as np


x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=50, size=10000)

i = 0
l = []
while len(l) < 3:
    if x[i] >= 36:
        l.append(x[i])
    i += 1

print l[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many 36's you've already seen and how many items you've looked at:

```
num_occurances = 0
index = 0

while num_occurances != 3:
    if x[index] >= 36:
        num_occurances += 1
    index += 1
print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the while loop for anything else an alternative solution might just be to mask the array.

```
import numpy as np


def nth_exceed(x, n, exceed):
    y = x[x > exceed][n-1]
    return np.where(x==y)

x = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=50, size = 10000)

nth_exceed(x, 3, 36)
```